# XSL-FOでのページ制御

Tags: xsl, xsl-fo

度々すみません。
XSL-FOでページの制御を行いたいと考えています。
CSS組版よりXSL-FO組版が有利な点として、ページ制御があると知って興味がわきました。

- 改ページの制御はどのように行いますか？
- 特定のオーサリングで改ページする場合、どのような方法が想定されますか？
- ページ数を減らすように調整するにはどのような方法がありますか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: どの様な制御をしたいということでしょうか？また、特定のオーサリングというのは例えばどういうものを指しますか？

Comment: 改ページの制御は、改ページする／しないを指しています。特定のオーサリングはは、マークアップとして何かの要素や属性を入力した場合に改ページするようにするといったものを指しています。例えば表を書いた後には改ページするようにする、といった要求です。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ・改ページの制御はどのように行いますか？

改ページ指定は、break-after, break-before, keep-together,keep-with-next, keep-with-previousといった属性を指定することで制御できます．
https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#d0e26492
これらは、CSS3-Multicolでも定義されていますが、keep-with-next, keep-with-previous についてはサポートされていません．
https://www.w3.org/TR/css-multicol-1/

> ・特定のオーサリングで改ページする場合、どのような方法が想定されますか？

"例えば表を書いた後には改ページするようにする" という指定をしたい場合、fo:table要素にbreak-after="page"と指定すると、表を出力した後に改ページします．

> ・ページ数を減らすように調整するにはどのような方法がありますか？

XSL-FOでは、コンテンツをページに流し込んでいきますので、データの編集により内容が増減すると、配置されるページが変わってきます．従ってあまり改ページ制御の指定を多用すると、かえってページ数が増えてしまう場合もあり得ます．

改ページによる制御ではありませんが、ページ数を減らすために、本文を二段組で出力したり、float要素により画像をフロート出力して本文を回り込ませたりすることで、ページ数を調整することがあります．